# Convertir una fecha a Numero usando PHP o Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hola como el titulo lo indica, quiero transformar una fecha a numero, es que haciendo un trabajo la forma de segmentar unos datos era convirtiendo la fecha a dato general en excel y la convertia a numeros, pero al pasarlo a PHP o JAVASCRIPT no permite esta conversion, queria saber si lguno me podria ayudar a transformar ese dato a numero

este es el codigo js que he estado usando

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#empleado_selec').on('click',function(){
  var fec_det = $('#fecha_det').val();
 var resulta =  Number(fec_det);
        alert (resulta); // cuerda
    })

})
```

Antes de que me digan que use Math.abs o otros algoritmos, no funcionan ya que me da un numero que no es igual a la tipifación en excel como "Formato general"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no me ha dado resultados y la verdad jajaja llevo asi como unos 4 meses si no es que mas xD ayuda por favor

Nuevo intento

```js
var mifecha = $('#fecha_det').val();
var fechaInicial = new Date("1900/01/01")
var diffTime = Math.abs(mifecha - fechaInicial);
var diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 
console.log(diffTime + " milisegundos entre las fechas!");
console.log(diffDays + " días sería el valor de Excel");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Salida

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sencillo. El número que buscas generar se obtiene calculando la diferencia con el día 1 en el calendario de Excel, 1/1/1900. Es cuestión de buscar la [documentación de Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/datevalue-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252) para ahorrarse esos cuatro meses ;)

```js
let mifecha = new Date("10/02/2022");
const fechaInicial = new Date("1900/01/01")
const diffTime = Math.abs(mifecha - fechaInicial);
const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 
console.log(diffTime + " milisegundos entre las fechas!");
console.log(diffDays + " días sería el valor de Excel");
```

Usé [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3224854/236345) para que quedara bonito el cálculo en JS.

Comment: hola ya lo estuve probando justo ahorita asi y no, me manda error

Comment: @RockMares Literalmente se puede probar aquí en el snippet y no hay ningún error al hacer clic en ejecutar. Por favor actualiza tu pregunta, AÑADE este nuevo intento y EL ERROR COMPLETO

Comment: ya la volvi a subir

Comment: ya quedo! era el formato de fecha que faltaba por convertir del primer dato! eres un maestro!

Comment: @RockMares súper! me alegra que te sirviera :D